# An Integer number in Excel returns a double number

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image: wierd displaying]

[Check out excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b8vgfYp4EodcJqLdm4EoskwzamrENc7i/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113760476310824788078&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Yellow colored cells does not return values as it displayed. It seems that the value is integer in excel, but actual value in POI is a double number. There's no formula, displaying options in the cell at all.

Here's the code that verifies acutal value.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
File file = new File("newSCIS.xlsx");
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
    String value = cell.getStringCellValue();

    System.out.printf("%20s \n", value);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526310/returning-decimal-instead-of-string-poi-jar

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a decimal number you can simply parse it to an int using

```
Math.round(floatNum);
```